# How to switch between maven version in mac

Tags: macos, maven

I have **maven3.1.1** and **maven3.2.5** installed on my mac.

When I do *mvn -version* it shows **maven3.1.1**

How can I switch to the other maven version 3.2.5 ?

Comment: delete the other version is quite simple no ?

Comment: @Hohenheim I want to keep the previous version as well so that if i need to go back to the previous version and i don't have to reinstall it.

Comment: maybe [this](https://ahoehma.wordpress.com/2009/09/03/how-to-use-multiple-maven-versions-parallel/) can help you

Comment: Download and install in `/usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.1.1` and `usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.2.5` and create a link in `/usr/share/maven` and switch this link...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Current bash profile would be pointing to the **maven version 3.1.1** as shown below

**~/.bash_profile**

```
export M2_HOME=/Users/yourusername/apache-maven-3.1.1 (Path where you have installed maven 3.1.1)
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

Change the bash profile as shown below

**~/.bash_profile**

```
export M2_HOME=/Users/yourusername/apache-maven-3.2.5 (Maven 3.2.5 path)
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

Restart the terminal and hit command `mvn -version` and now it will be pointing to the latest version.

Comment: Don't use M2_HOME anymore. Only the PATH entry is neccessary. Just simply `PATH=$PATH:/.../apache-maven-3.1.1/bin` not more... (See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5607).

Answer (score 2):

Using SDKMan might be a simpler way to switch between multiple Maven versions.

1) Install SDKMan which is a one-off thing: http://sdkman.io/install.html

2) Do `sdk install maven yourVersion`

3) To switch: `sdk install maven anotherVersion`

4) To switch again: `sdk use maven yourVersion`

SDKMan should simplify such operations for several other software frameworks like Java, Groovy, Spring, Gradle, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to create a soft link. Suppose you have two version like -

**maven-v1** and
**maven-v2**

Now if you want to use **maven-v1** then create a soft link -

```
ln -s /installation/directory/of/maven-v1 maven
```

Then in your `.bash_profile` export `M2_HOME` pointing this directory -

```
export M2_HOME=/path/to/maven
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

If you are doing this at first time then you need to restart your terminal.But after that you just need to change the soft link to you expected version. Suppose, now you want to use `maven-v2`; just change the existing soft link -

```
ln -sf /installation/directory/of/maven-v2 maven
```

Now you don't need to restart the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

In your ~/.bash_profile

Download the tar of the maven version you want to use and extract the contents you want to use. Example Maven 3.1.1

```
 export M2_HOME=/Users/<path to maven>/apache-maven-3.1.1
 export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

If you have zsh, then change the ~/.zprfile

Answer (score 0):

do not use M2_HOME. directly go for export PATH=$PATH:/usr/{maven...path}/bin

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a function for ~/.zshrc and ~/.bashrc files to choose a different maven version according to the project without having to install more maven versions but taking advantage of docker.

So I use my maven installed in my machine with: `mvn clean install`
And I use my maven in docker with: `maven jdk8 clean install` or `maven jdk11 package` for example.
Here the function:

```
# executes a containerized version of maven so you won't have to install to your computer.
# you need to have docker installed and running.
# you can specify 'jdk8' or 'jdk11' as first argument to switch jdk.
# if not specified, jdk11 is the default.
# usage example: 
# /your/maven/project/directory - $ maven jdk8 clean install
# /your/maven/project/directory - $ maven clean package
maven() {
    if [[ "$1" == "jdk8" ]]; then
        docker run --rm -v $PWD:/usr/src/app -v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2 -w /usr/src/app maven:3.8-adoptopenjdk-8 mvn "${@:2}"
    elif [[ "$1" == "jdk11" ]]; then
        docker run --rm -v $PWD:/usr/src/app -v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2 -w /usr/src/app maven:3.8-eclipse-temurin-11 mvn "${@:2}"
    else 
        docker run --rm -v $PWD:/usr/src/app -v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2 -w /usr/src/app maven:3.8-eclipse-temurin-11 mvn "$@"
    fi
}
```